# the code is suposed to print the largest number to the right of the current number, and for the last number it shoukd print -1

Tags: java, arrays

the code is suposed to print the largest number to the right of the current number, and for the last number it shoukd print -1

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maxtoright {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner sc = newScanner(System.in);
        int t= sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0) {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int a[]= new int[n];        
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
                }       
                if(n==1) {          
                    System.out.print("-1");
                }
                if(n==2) {
                    System.out.print(a[n-1]+"-1");
                }       
                if(n>2) {
                for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++) {
                    int max= a[i+1];
                    for(int j=i+1;j<n-2;j++) {
                        if(a[j]>max) {
                            max=a[j];
                        } 
        //              System.out.print(max+" ");
                    }            
                System.out.print(max+" ");
                }       
            System.out.print(a[n-1]+" "+"-1");
        }
    }
}
```

Blockquote

Comment: Is that what you need?

Input           // 2   4    3    7   19   7   1   10  17

Output       //19  19  19  19  17  17  17  17  -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the requirement is to for every element in an array find the largest element to its right. (For last element it would be -1)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int[] input = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                input[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                System.out.print("-1");
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                System.out.print(input[n - 1] + "-1");
            } else {
                findLargeNumber(input);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void findLargeNumber(int[] input) {
        int n = input.length;
        int max = input[n - 1];
        System.out.print(input[n - 1] + " " + -1 + "\n");

        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            int temp = input[i];
            if (temp > max) {
                max = temp;
            }
            System.out.print(input[i] + " " + max + "\n");
        }
    }

Output: for input {2, 4, 3, 7, 19, 7, 23, 1, 10, 17};

17 -1
10 17
 1 17
23 23
 7 23
19 23
 7 23
 3 23
 4 23
 2 23
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have an unsorted array like:
[1, 10, 20, 18, 30]
Then you want the user to get the user input, which is a number in an array and find the biggest number to its right. So for example, if the input is 10 it will output 30, but if it's the last number it will just output -1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //An unsorted array
        final int[] array = {1, 10, 20, 18, 30};

        //Here we get the user input
        final var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final var input = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(findBiggestValue(array, input));
    }

    private static int findBiggestValue(int[] array, int input){
        //Find index of the input in the array
        var index = -1;
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            var entry = array[x];
            if(entry == input){
                index = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        //If no index is found, throw an exception
        if(index == -1){
            throw new RuntimeException("The number inserted isn't in the array!");
        }

        //If the index is the last entry return -1
        if(index == array.length - 1){
            return -1;
        }

        //Find biggest value after the index that we found previously
        var maxValue = input;
        for(var entry : array){
            if(entry > maxValue){
                maxValue = entry;
            }
        }

        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it has should work something like this: a[6]={16,17,4,3,5,2} it should print 17,5,5,5,2,-1 because for first case the largest number to the right of 16 is 17 then for next case the largest number to the right of 17 is 5, then for the next case the largest number to the right of 4 is 5 , and largest number to the right of 3 is 5 and the largest(only) number to the right of 5 is 2 and for the last number as there is no other element to the right of 2 hence print -1.

Comment: You can just use the method findBiggestValue with every entry in the array